# Sum of the series $\frac{(-3)^{n-1}}{8^n}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, summation

It might looks obvious to you but I don't manage to find the sum: 
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-3)^{n-1}}{8^n}$$
Can anyone help me ?
Thanks

Comment: What is your summand? Is it $\left(\frac{9}{2n}\right)^8$ or is it $\frac{9}{2n^8}$?

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake, I'm going to edit my message.

Comment: Please use latex to write the math in your question

Comment: Wow! After the editing the series looks **very** different...!

Comment: Yes, I'm really sorry, I should have focused on this exercise rather than doing an other one. I apologize

Comment: Is it $3^{n-1}$ or $3^n-1$.

Answer (score 3):

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac9{2n^8}=\frac92\zeta(8)=\frac92\frac{\pi^8}{9,450}=\frac{\pi^8}{2,100}$$

You'll need some rather powerful methods, me believes, to reach this result, like Fourier Series...

Comment: +1! Did Mathematica or some paper came up with this?

Comment: My bad, I was actually doing an other exercise and thus I mixed the datas. Nevertheless, your answer is interesting and I'm grateful

Comment: In fact I remember I had to do this in Advanced Calculus class in undergraduate studies, when in Fourier Series...up to $\,\zeta(10)\;$ , if I remember correctly. It was nasty and looooong, but I seem to remember that it was possible. For odd naturals it doesn't work, though.

Comment: Just found it in [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function), where a formula for even zetas is given. So, you were forced to use fourier series?

Comment: @DonAntonio : the question now looks totally different from your answer.  I suspect the question was edited.

Comment: Hehe...yes @chubakueno: back then we only had the academic web BITNET, not internet at all.

Answer (score 2):

Hint

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-3)^n-1}{8^n}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(-\frac{3}{8}\right)^n-\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left( \frac{1}{8} \right)^n$$

is the difference of two geometric series.

Answer (score 2):

After you completely changed the question, it *seems to be* you want the series

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-3)^{n-1}}{8^n}=-\frac13\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(-\frac38\right)^n\stackrel{\text{geom. series}}=-\frac13\frac{-\frac38}{1+\frac38}=\ldots$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty {(-3)^{n-1} \over 8^n}={-1 \over 3}*\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac {-3}{8}\right)^{n}$$This is a geometric progression with $|r|\lt 1$. Hence its sum is $\frac a{1-r}$. Therefore $$S=\left(\frac {-1}3\right)*\left(\frac {-3}{8} \over {1-\left(\frac {-3}{8}\right)}\right)=\left(\frac {-1}3\right)*\left(\frac {-3}{11}\right)=\frac 1{11}$$